# I need to set allowcredentials for a wildcard origin in .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.0

```
options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", 
                  builder => builder.WithOrigins("*")
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                                    .AllowCredentials())
```

This code is showing a CORS error:

> The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported.

How can I solve this? How can I add a wildcard origin with `AllowCredentials`?

Comment: Remove ```.AllowCredentials()```  or ```WithOrigins```

Comment: Allowing credentialed requests from all origins would be insecure. See https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't do that

as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests):

> The CORS specification also states that setting origins to "*" (all
> origins) is invalid if the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is
> present.

and this part in the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

> When responding to a credentialed request:
>
> The server must not specify the "*" wildcard for the
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin response-header value, but must instead
> specify an explicit origin;

for example: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
https://example.com

> The server must not specify the "*" wildcard for
> the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response-header value, but must
> instead specify an explicit list of header names;
> for example,Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
> The server
> must not specify the "*" wildcard for the Access-Control-Allow-Methods
> response-header value, but must instead specify an explicit list of
> method names;

for example, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET

> The server must not specify the "*" wildcard for the
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers response-header value, but must instead
> specify an explicit list of header names;

for example, Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Encoding, Kuma-Revision

If you set with  `WithOrigins("*")` it would add  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to the response header